# get am/pm in gmt timezone

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I am trying to get am/pm in gmt timezone but code is crashing with this error. How can I change existing/default timezone which I pick from timepicker in GMT am/pm  ?

COde:

```
 String selectedHour="15";
        String selectedMinute="32";
        String am_pm="PM";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM a", Locale.US);
        Date testDate = null;
        try {
            testDate = sdf.parse(selectedHour+" "+selectedMinute+" "+am_pm);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("a");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
        System.out.println(".....Date..." + newFormat);
```

Error:

```
System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "15 32 PM" (at offset 2)  
System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code should be like this to parse date

```
testDate = sdf.parse(selectedHour+":"+selectedMinute+" "+am_pm);
```